# R reading csv file with read.csv

Tags: r, csv

With this script:

```
# I) Go to the working directory
setwd("/home/***/Desktop/***")

# II) Verify the current working directory
print(getwd())

# III) Load te nedded package
require("csv")

# IV) Read the desired file
read.csv(file="serious-injury-outcome-indicators-2000-18-csv.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

I tried to read this file:
[Serious injury outcome indicators: 2000–18 – CSV](https://www.stats.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/Serious-injury-outcome-indicators/Serious-injury-outcome-indicators-200018/Download-data/serious-injury-outcome-indicators-2000-18-csv.csv)

But the output in the consol is not well, Can someone try it and tell me if he encoutred the same problem.
Thanks

Comment: Another option is to load `library(readr)` and use `read_csv`. This loads data as a `data.frame` and a `tibble`.

Comment: I've never seen the `csv` package used - there's a `read.csv` built in to R. Have you tried the default version?

Comment: But more importantly, can you be more specific than "the output in the consol is not well"? Is there an error message? Any warnings? What do you see? Why do you think it is wrong? Perhaps try assigning the result `d <- read.csv(...)` and have a look at `d`?

Comment: i think you would profit from adding `dec="."` like so: `df<-read.table("C:/Users/***/serious-injury-outcome-indicators-2000-18-csv.csv", header=T, sep=",", dec=".")` but other than that it looks fine

Comment: @D.J Why? `dec = "."` is the default. And why switch to `read.table`?

Comment: @Gregor Thomas You are right it is standard and not necessary. i probably put it there for the same reason i'm using the `read.table()` function. i am used to the greater freedom and had a sneaky teacher who changed just enough stuff in the practice files to make standard templates like csv & csv2 unusable.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the file directly from the website:

```
dta <- url("https://www.stats.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/Serious-injury-outcome-indicators/Serious-injury-outcome-indicators-200018/Download-data/serious-injury-outcome-indicators-2000-18-csv.csv")
injury <- read.csv(dta, header=TRUE)
str(injury)
# 'data.frame': 2460 obs. of  13 variables:
#  $ Series_reference: chr  "W_A11" "W_A11" "W_A11" "W_A11" ...
#  $ Period          : chr  "2000-02" "2001-03" "2002-04" "2003-05" ...
#  $ Type            : chr  "Moving average" "Moving average" "Moving average" "Moving average" ...
#  $ Data_value      : num  59.7 60 59 59 61.3 ...
#  $ Lower_CI        : num  50.9 51.2 50.3 50.3 52.5 ...
#  $ Upper_CI        : num  68.4 68.8 67.7 67.7 70.2 ...
#  $ Units           : chr  "Injuries" "Injuries" "Injuries" "Injuries" ...
#  $ Indicator       : chr  "Number" "Number" "Number" "Number" ...
#  $ Cause           : chr  "Assault" "Assault" "Assault" "Assault" ...
#  $ Validation      : chr  "Validated" "Validated" "Validated" "Validated" ...
#  $ Population      : chr  "Whole pop" "Whole pop" "Whole pop" "Whole pop" ...
#  $ Age             : chr  "All ages" "All ages" "All ages" "All ages" ...
#  $ Severity        : chr  "Fatal" "Fatal" "Fatal" "Fatal" ...
```